# Delete empty rows in jTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am trying to remove empty rows in table. I am detecting empty rows by checking  first field(Register number - primary). But on clicking the button it removes only half of the empty rows and on next click another half rows of empty rows are deleted and it produces *ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException*.  I don't know whats wrong in my code. Thanks in advance.

```
DefaultTableModel dtm=(DefaultTableModel) jTable4.getModel();
    int i=dtm.getRowCount();       
    for(int j=0;j<i;j++)
         {

         if(!(jTable4.getValueAt(j, 0) != null 
         && jTable4.getValueAt(j, 0).toString().trim().length() != 0) )
         {
               dtm.removeRow(j);
         }

         }
```

Comment: The problem is, when you delete a row from the table, you change the number of rows.  What I've done in the past is generated a list of row indices I want to delete, sort it in reverse order and delete the rows backwards, this prevents the changes in row indices from affecting the remaining operations you need to perfom

Comment: Thanks @MadProgrammer .I looped in reverse order and it works.  But i am not clear in above code.  Initially i have assigned rowcount to 'i'.  how it can change on executing the for loop(no new assigns for 'i'). However Thanks bro.

Comment: To go in reverse you can also change `for(int j=0;j<i;j++)` into `for(int j=i-1;j>=0;j--)` and that way you should not get `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException` and your DefaultTableModel will take care of the row count for you. If you need to get an updated row count just use this again `i=dtm.getRowCount();`

Comment: Instead of `j<i` you should have (at least) been using `j < dtm.getRowCount()`, this would have checked against the "actual" number of rows and not the number of rows you started with, remember, when you remove a row, the row number changes